# How to compare boost::string_ref to std::string

Tags: c++, string, boost, stl

I'm trying to make `boost::string_ref` working as I want to, but I'm facing a problem right now - following code does not compile:

```
 #include <boost/utility/string_ref.hpp> 
 #include <iostream> 
 #include <string> 

 using namespace std;

int main() {
   string test = "test";
   boost::string_ref rtest(test);
   cout << (rtest == "test")<<endl;
}
```

and the gcc throws 30kB error log, starting with

```
source.cpp: In function 'int main()':
source.cpp:10:19: error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'boost::string_ref {aka boost::basic_string_ref<char, std::char_traits<char> >}' and 'const char [5]')
    cout << (rtest == "test")<<endl;
                   ^
```

How to compare `boost::string_ref` to `std::string`?

Comment: Can you include the log just up to the first complete `error` line?

Comment: @DrewDormann http://liveworkspace.org/code/2dWWjs$0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Honestly, I'd just avoid using `string_ref` entirely until it matures. The fact that you can't compare a `string_ref` to a `std::string` or a `const char *` out of the box should set alarm bells ringing (looks like they forgot to write a bunch of comparison operators), and worse, it doesn't look like the library received sufficient testing (e.g. [bug 8067](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/8067)!).

Comment: It looks like the upcoming [Boost 1.54](http://www.boost.org/users/history/version_1_54_0.html) will resolve this, which should make `boost::string_ref` much more useful.

Comment: `string_ref` is mature now in Boost 1.60, comparison works out of the box. As for the reason to use `string_ref` check [this](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/utility/doc/html/string_ref.html#string_ref.examples) out.

Answer (score 1):

Just make a `string_ref` out of the string.  They are very cheap to construct.  Though against a string literal, you may want to include the length.  Otherwise it's going to iterate once to find the end of the string, and then iterate again to compare them.  Just make sure that if you change the string, you keep the count up to date.

```
cout << (rtest == boost::string_ref("test",4)) << endl;
```

With a `std::string`, you don't need to worry about the count, because `string_ref` will just call the `size()` member function, which is also very cheap.

Comment: I don't see how the original comparison fails to compile. There's already an equality operator defined for `string_refs` and a `string_ref` constructor that takes a `charT*`, but apparently the compiler is not picking it since template parameter deduction fails. Do you know why is that happening? BTW, I didn't downvote.

Comment: "*Though against a string literal, you may want to include the length.*" Wow, that's sad. String literals are `const char[N]`s already; the size is provided. There's *no reason* why `string_ref` shouldn't have a template constructor that takes the size.

Comment: @NicolBolas: It would still need to search for the null terminator.  A `const char[N]` may hold a c-string that terminates at any point before `N`.

Comment: this is really ugly :( and why do we HAVE TO create `boost::string_ref` for that if it can be compared to `string literal` (`const char[N]`) - I know using `string_reaf` is cheap, but not using it is cheapier and I'm really trying to write high performance code right now.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: "*A `const char[N]` may hold a c-string that terminates at any point before `N`.*" And it might not. In the absence of the ability to detect whether a parameter is a string literal or not, I would go with the preponderance of the evidence. And 9 times out of 10, a `const char[N]` is a string literal. Let the 1 in 10 use the explicit sizing.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley metaparse should be able to find the null terminator at compile-time.